# Premade Materials in Blender render?

Tags: modeling, materials, append

Does Blender Render have pre-made material like a chromed/metal material like other 3D softwares like 3dsMax or Maya? I know that there are more options on cycles, but does the blender render have this too?

Comment: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Material/Online_Material_Library

Comment: Ni, BI doesn't have a material library included. We collected links to resources here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender/15361#15361

Comment: @cgeaton That is a cool link, but I think the addon only applies to cycles, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are **no templates** so to speak. You can create or buy your own templates though, and bring them into your project using blender **append functionality.** The blender foundation [announced a project to improve this system](http://www.blender.org/press/18-anticipated-blender-development-projects-of-2015/).

To create your own template library, open new blender file (you won't want other work in here). create a bunch of spheres, and build the materials you want. I recommend naming them carefully, since you will be pulling them by name alone.

Once you have your library, you can link or append the materials, I recommend appened, since it allows you tho change the materials in your .blend, while link you have to change them in the master, and it will affect all the files using that file.

To appened, go to *file* > *append* or hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

[image]

and navigate to your .blend with the materials in it. When you click on the .blend, you will see allot of folders. Click on the one called material

[image]

You will see the names of your materials. select the ones you want for your project, and then tweak them to your needs!